# Oracle Webcenter sites perspective buttons are not working in eclipse [ Developer Tools: Reading all asset types returned status: Forbidden ]

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, webcenter, webcenter-sites

I've installed the `com.fatwire.EclipseCSDT_11.1.1.v8_0_r181775.zip` (CSDT) plugin to eclipse (mars) for webcenter sites.

But when I click on create new template or any CSDT buttons it shows below error in error log window.

[image]

If I open it, it shows as below:

[image]

Can someone please help to resolve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found user configured for webcenter sites was not assigned in the `REST Security` group.

Assign the User to the `REST Security` group and restart your eclipse.

It will start working :)

Happy coding!!